# How to write to multiple indices of an array at the same time in Julia?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I would like to see something like this working in Julia:

```
using Distributed
addprocs(4)

@everywhere arr = Array{Int}(undef, 10)
for i = 1:10
    @spawn arr[i] = i
end
```

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: `SharedArrays`? The example is almost equivalent to the one [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/distributed-computing/#Parallel-Map-and-Loops) (scroll down a bit).

Comment: Thanks, I also found that in my code, changing the @spawn to Threads.@spawn works just as fine.

Comment: Parallelizing using threads is something totally different than parallelizing using multiprocessing with Distributed. When you changed to `Threads.@spawn ` the first to line along `@everywhere`  are obsolete and you still need to make sure that your `@spawn`ed thread has done its job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following ways to parallelize the process.

1. Threads (requires setting `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` system variable)

   ```
   arr = Array{Int}(undef, 10)
   Threads.@threads for i = 1:10
       arr[i] = i
   end
   ```
2. `SharedArrays`

   ```
   using Distributed, SharedArrays
   addprocs(4)
   arr = SharedVector{Int}(10)
   @sync @distributed for i in 1:10
       arr[i] = i 
   end
   ```

   Note that a common error is to forget to place `@sync` before `@distributed` that does not have an aggregator function (see the last example).
3. Aggregate the results of your distributed computation

   ```
   using Distributed
   addprocs(4)
   arr = @distributed (append!) for i in 1:10
       [i]
   end
   ```

Comment: In my situation, I can't use the first one because my function isn't thread-safe. I also couldn't be able to implement my code as the second one and the third one seems to be more like a syntax sugar and not as peaceful as the others. However, my code magically works. I will open another post soon to ask if I do everything properly, please take a look. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I use the third one because sometimes `SharedArrays` seems unstable to me. The third one makes sense whenever calculating `[i]` takes a significant amount of time (e.g. 10ms).